# Span should be hidden

Tags: html, css

My html output is actual this: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3408/
[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

And when a user clicks on one of the columns (for eg the column in the middle it should look like this:

[image]

My html has a simple construction: 
The numbers are each in a `span` with the class `numbers`:

```
.numbers{
  width:70px;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
}
.text{
  width:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

And the text is contained in spans with the class `text`. 
These two boxes `numbers` and `text` are in a `span` with the class `ContainerSpan`:

```
.ContainerSpan {
    float:left;
    width:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Actually my jquery works! The only thing i have problems with is that how i said red text is not hidden at the beginning! I hope you can help me! Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3408/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

  <span id="BOX">
    <span id="firstSpan" class="ContainerSpan">
      <span class="numbers">
        <p>02342</p>
        <p>24500</p>
        <p>34510</p>
        <p>24500</p>
      </span>
      <span class="text">
        <p>first</p>
        <p>second</p>
        <p>third</p>
        <p>forth</p>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span id="secondSpan" class="ContainerSpan">
      <span class="numbers">
        <p>92342</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3410/) version.

I added `display: none;` to the `.text` CSS and conditionally called `.show()` to display the correct column text. Additionally any `.text` currently visible is hidden beforehand so only one column is displayed at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking this.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fus5/

added these to CSS:

```
.text{
  width:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  display:none;
}
.ContainerSpan.ShowFull{
    width: 270px;
}
.ContainerSpan.ShowFull .text{
    display: block;
}
```

and JS

```
$('.ContainerSpan').click(function(){
  $('.ContainerSpan').removeClass('ShowFull');
  $(this).addClass('ShowFull');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('.ContainerSpan').click(function(){
  // Reset values
  $('.text').css("display", "none");
  $('.ContainerSpan').width(70);

  // Show current column text
  $(this).find('.text').css("display", "block");
  $(this).width(270);
});
</script>

<style>

.text{
  width:200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  /* Add default display none for .text */
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3411/